# How to create a shadow gradient border by using pure CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

I am struggling to create the attached div for a webpage. The border of the div has some kind of shadow gradient background grey color. I knew I can use linear gradient for border-image but this only give gradient colors for all four edges. Here I want to give the gradient for dark grey color in linear gradient for the bottom edge but light grey color gradient for the vertical edge (left and right). It is little bit tricky. I tried the following code but only give gradient colors from dark to light from bottom edge to both vertical edge. It does not give the border gradient colors I want. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="module">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero pariatur corporis quaerat voluptatum eos tempora temporibus nisi voluptates sed, exercitationem sequi dolore culpa incidunt accusamus, quasi unde reprehenderit ea molestias.
</div>
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
}

.module {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: black;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: 
    radial-gradient(      
      grey, 
      hsl(0, 0%, 98%)
    ) 1 100%;
  border-image-slice: 1 10% 45;
  border-image-outset: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you're trying to achieve? A screenshot, or some kind of figure of sorts.

Comment: So you're trying to achieve a [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) ?

Comment: Have you tried box-shadow?

Comment: As mentioned before, try `box-shadow`. Here's an example `box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px hsl(0, 0%, 80%);`

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. Yes I think box-shadow is the way I should go.

Answer (score 2):

The shadow property doesn't provide a way to add shadows.

However, you can achieve this by creating a pseudo-element and bluring it. Then placing it on the position you want underneath the element that needs to have the shadow.

Here's how to do it:

```css
/* 
* Element we use to apply the shadow.
* You can use any element instead. Just note 
* it requires the use of `position: relative` 
* and some `background`.
*/
.box {
  /* Required properties */
  position: relative;
  background: white;

  /* Use  your own styles here */
  margin: 45px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 123px;  
}

/* 
* This is what creates the shadow.
*/
.box:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, #ff3d00 0%, #0400ff 100% );
  transform: translate3d(0px, 20px, 0) scale(0.95);
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: var(0.7);
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

/* 
* Prevents issues when the parent creates a 
* stacking context. (For example, using the transform
* property )
*/
.box::after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Test 1
</div>
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/YzeOLLa

If you want to speed up the process you can use [this online generator](https://alvarotrigo.com/shadow-gradients/) I created a few days ago.